# I want to know which language is useful for create a web page

Tags: json

I have going to do a project on web application.I choose the topic as online shopping.I have no idea about the project.so kindly help me.which programing language I should prefer? what are all the things I tent to do?

Comment: Just want to ask why you want to do it? You clearly have no idea about programing, then why you want to create a online shop project?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to know the two basic languages of the web. HTML and CSS. If you want to do any thin more than display a basic webpage, you will need to know some basic javascript. For your specific use case of online shopping you will most likely need some sort of server set up to run your backend along with a database. There are hundreds of different languages for this. I would look into Full Stack Web Development as a start. I would highly recommend learning the basics of HTML, CSS, and javascript before you dive into Full Stack Development right away. Without knowledge of those 3 languages, you cant do much on the web.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to write code start learning html,css,js, and php

but if you just want to create such application use wordpress instead to save you time and some trouble

Answer (score 0):

If u want to build online shopping app completly from scratch . Do it from Django , Nodejs. This is a great framework to start and u will definetly learn a lot while doing this project. Use MongoDb as a database and Angular or Vuejs in frontend . I know its very tough but it helps u to learn lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ruby on rails` to make your web application. There are many gems of ruby using which you can add many functionalities with your app easily.

As you selected topic online shopping, there is `spree` gem in ruby using which you can make a base app of online shopping within few minutes and then change it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the web application really fast, I suggest you to use open source CMS system. They got loads of templates and free resources. It is written in PHP.

- [OpenCart](https://www.opencart.com/)
- [Magento](https://magento.com/home)

If you want to write the application from scratch, I suggest you to use [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) / [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) as Frontend, [laravel](https://laravel.com/) as API server and Backend.